# Hadoop data structure to save block report in namenode

Tags: hdfs

Hadoop saves files in form of blocks on data nodes(DN) and metadata about files is saved into namenodes(NN). Whenever any file is being read by a client then NN sends a read-pipeline (list of DNs) from where file blocks are to be picked up. Read pipeline consists of **nearest** DNs (w.r.t client) to serve read request.

I am curious to know how NN keeps information about DN for blocks of file. I mean the data structure. Is it a graph with information of all replicas location of DN? and later on while creating a read-pipeline some algo is used to find shortest path between client and corresponding DNs?

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a term named "read pipeline". For read/write request, the granularity is block level. Generally the write pipeline is like: client -> DN1 -> DN2 -> DN3. For read, client connects the NN for the DN list that hold replicas of the block to read. Then the client reads the data from the nearest DN directly, without involving other DNs (in case of error, client may try another DN in the list).

As to the "data structure" of DN for block information, there is a block -> DNs in-memory mapping maintained by NN. Basically the mapping is a map. To update the map, DNs will periodically report its local replica of blocks to NN.

Client is free to choose the nearest DN for read. For this, the HDFS should be topology-aware. From the [HDFS architecture doc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html):

> To minimize global bandwidth consumption and read latency, HDFS tries to satisfy a read request from a replica that is closest to the reader. If there exists a replica on the same rack as the reader node, then that replica is preferred to satisfy the read request. If angg/ HDFS cluster spans multiple data centers, then a replica that is resident in the local data center is preferred over any remote replica.